# Angular make http get request then with data from get request make put request

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I want to upload multiple images on AWS S3.

First on frontend i upload images and show the preview of images to the user, then inside for loop i'm running every time function uploadFilesSimulator to upload every image.

```
  prepareFilesList(files: Array<any>) {
  for (const item of files) {
  item.progress = 0;
  this.files.push(item);

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (filedata) => {
    item.url = reader.result + '';
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(item);

  this.uploadFilesSimulator(item);
}
```

}

First i make get request to my node js API. The result is key and url. 
Then after url is fetched I run put request to add image to that url.

```
  uploadFilesSimulator(file: any) {
this.formService.getUploadUrl().subscribe(data => {
  let upload = this.formService.uploadImage(data.url, file).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, err => console.log(err));
});
```

This is working but i want to avoid nested subsriptions.
What rxjs operator should i use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three operators can do that: `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, and `concatMap`. The more appropriate for your case is `mergeMap`, even though for your particular case there won't be any difference because `this.formService.getUploadUrl()` will only emit one event.

For more details, I suggest this excellent web site: https://rxmarbles.com/

You can use it like this:

```
uploadFilesSimulator(file: any) {
    return this.formService.getUploadUrl().pipe(
        mergeMap(data => this.formService.uploadImage(data.url, file))
    );
}
```

Comment: For some reason it won't trigger anything. Just nothing happens, i tried with switchmap margemap and concatmap.

Comment: getUploadUrl(): Observable<UploadUrl> {
    return this.http.get<UploadUrl>(`${this.url}/upload`);
  }

  uploadImage(url: string, file: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  file.type
    });

    return this.http.put(url, file, {headers: headers });
  }

Comment: That's because there is no `subscribe`. Only subscribing to the observable will trigger the request, but I removed it from your code because this is a good practice to subscribe in the components (not in the service)

Comment: And thank you for your answer and this great website !

Comment: I got it. Thank you again.